# Unable to get max _id value in MongoDB Aggregation using Java code

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation

Statement: I am trying to get max _id values for a dataset.

Problem: It's returning all the _id values.

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(collection);          
AggregateIterable<Document> docs = coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("Dept", "IT")),Aggregates.group("$_id", Accumulators.max("_id", "$_id"))));
for(Document doc : docs) {System.out.println(doc.toJson());}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** You are grouping on `_id` and trying to find the maximum `_id` in the group which obviously would be one for each group. Instead, you need to find max from all filtered documents.

**The following code can get us the expected output:**

```
MongoCollection coll = db.getCollection(collection);

AggregateIterable docs = coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("Dept", "IT")),
        Aggregates.group(null, Accumulators.max("_id", "$_id"))));
for (Document doc : docs) {
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr S Sharma. Your suggestion didn't work, but I appreciate it. Please find the mongo shell command, it has no problem with group on id column, 

db.getCollection("Emp").aggregate([
{ $match: { Dept : { $eq: "IT"} } },
{$group :{_id : "$oid", max_id : {$max : "$_id"}}}
])

Comment: Can you please update your question with some sample data and expected output?

Comment: 1. Expected Output:     "_id" : "5d5818240285461e54bedcf8"


2. Sample Data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d9059f0b31921a4916a0c"), 
    "EmpID" : "1001", 
    "EmpName" : "John", 
    "Sal" : 30000.0, 
    "DOB" : ISODate("1989-06-09T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "Age" : 31.0, 
    "Dept" : "IT"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5818240285461e54bedcf8"), 
    "EmpID" : "1005", 
    "EmpName" : "Henry", 
    "Sal" : 35000.0, 
    "DOB" : ISODate("1995-02-09T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "Age" : 21.0, 
    "Dept" : "IT"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I found my answer,

Solution: we need to group on non-aggregated field.

Code:

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(collection);
        
AggregateIterable<Document> docs = coll.aggregate(
        Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("Dept", "IT")),
                Aggregates.group("EmpId", Accumulators.max("id", "$_id"))
                )                   
        );

for(Document doc : docs) {
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example: You can try this
By using this I am getting maximum date from `logDate` column and I am grouping it as MachineNames(As per my requirement)

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection  = databases.getCollection("Smx_22234_ShiftOEEDaily");

AggregateIterable<Document> maxLogDate = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.group("$machineName", Accumulators.max("maxlogdate", "$logDate"))));
```